# How to get instance of Adapter Product in Magento 2.1.x

Tags: magento2, event-observer

In Magento 1.x it uses

```
"instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product"
```

How can I do this with Magento 2?

Comment: What u want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want affected entity IDs of products for my observer.

Comment: Are u solved it?@Pradip